# How to have multiple python version on the jenkins server

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, devops

I have some infra scripts which support python 2.7 and some test cases which support 3.7, So when I am passing the path of the python 3.7 (/usr/lib/python3.7), the script is not able to detect it and the build fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- use something like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to distinguish Python versions
- run your scripts inside a Docker container (you need to have Docker installed on the agents). Something like:

`docker run -i -v ${ver_2_scripts_dir}:/src python:2-alpine python /src/my_script.py`

`docker run -i -v ${ver_3_scripts_dir}:/src python:3-alpine python /src/another_script.py`